# Wicket WebResponse Attachment Header with UTF-8 charackers?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, wicket, httpwebresponse

In wicket project I use request handler for file downloading. Everything is works good until I have file with non standard encoding like utf-8.

I use this code for generate response

```
@Override
   public void respond(IRequestCycle requestCycle)
   {
      WebResponse response = (WebResponse) requestCycle.getResponse();
      response.setAttachmentHeader(briefcaseDocument.getName());
      response.setContentType(briefcaseDocument.getMimeType());
      response.setContentLength(briefcaseDocument.getSize());
      InputStream inputStream = null;
      OutputStream outputStream = null;
      try
      {
         inputStream = briefcaseDocument.getInputStream();
         outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
         IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException("unable to push file content", e);
      }
      finally
      {
         IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
         IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
      }
   }
```

but if document has special characketrs I get empty file name. For example:

ćććć is:

```
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="   ";
```

ćwiek is:

```
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=" wiek";
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) stack topic and change code like this:

```
 String fileName = briefcaseDocument.getName();
 String encoded = URLEncoder
         .encode(briefcaseDocument.getName(), "UTF-8");

 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment" +
 ((!Strings.isEmpty(fileName)) ? ("; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"; filename*=UTF-8''"+encoded) : "" ));
```

and then I get as result:

```
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="  "; filename*=UTF-8''%C4%87%C5%BC
```

and file name present good, but I don't feel good with this solution ;) How to make wicket set file name properly?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/ this is the proper way.

Since 7.0.0-M1 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4934) Wicket does this automatically for you.